# How to customize Angular Flash Messages

Tags: css, angular

I'm using [angular-2-flash-messages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-flash-messages) in my angular project along with angular material. I seem to have a problem when using it in angular material dashboard.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyj7G.png) is how it appears

This is how I use a flash message

```
this.flashMessage.show('You have successfully logged in', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 50000});
```

I tried to move the message content of the flash message to center via css but they are not working. Only either bootstrap 'alert-success' or 'alert-danger' works with it.

In one of the issues in [github repository](https://github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=css) the owner has answered on customizing the css but all attempts failed.

How can I center the message contents ?

Comment: This is a CSS problem, and you wlil have to post a [mcve] to receive proper help. You can copy your HTML with the flash message from the element inspector and then look for the CSS in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div [ngClass]="{alert:true, 
                 'alert-info': message.style=='alert-info',
                 'alert-danger': message.style=='alert-danger'
                 'alert-success': message.style=='alert-success'  ">
   <center>
      <flash-messages></flash-messages>
   </center>
</div>
```

// si usas bootsrap, puedes usar las clases de este y enviar en el envío

```
this.flashMessage.show('You have successfully logged in', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 50000});
this.flashMessage.show('You have logged', {cssClass: 'alert-info', timeout: 50000});
this.flashMessage.show('error de login', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 50000});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about displaying flash messages in HTML center tag?

Like this:

```
<center>
   <flash-messages></flash-messages>
</center>
```

But you need to apply bootstrap style on the parent tag

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
   <center>
      <flash-messages></flash-messages>
   </center>
</div>
```

and **don't pass css classes with show function**.